# SQL Server 2008 how to Subtotal group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subtotal

I am trying to add subtotal in query for the following table :

```
Table A:          Table B:                     Table C:

ID    Name        ID     Name      SubOf       ID      Name      SubOf
===   ======      =====  =======   =====       ======  ======    =====
1     Name 1      1.1    SName 1   1           1.1.1   SSName 1  1.1
2     Name 2      1.2    SName 2   2           1.1.2   SSName 2  1.1
3     Name 3      1.3    SName 3   3           1.1.3   SSName 3  1.1
```

Table **Transaction**:

```
ID        Qty
======    =======
1.1.1     100
1.1.2     50
1.1.3     200
1.1.1     100
1.1.2     50
1.1.3     200
1.1.1     100
1.1.2     50
1.1.3     200
1.1.1     100
1.1.2     50
1.1.3     200
1.1.1     100
```

I want to select my data like this :

Desired results:

```
ID        Name        Total
======    =======     =======
1         Name 1      1500    ->Total ID 1 
1.1       sName 1     1500    ->Total ID 1.1
1.1.1     ssName 1     500
1.1.2     ssName 2     200
1.1.3     ssName 3     800
```

How can I add subtotal like the result table?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your table structure is not normalized. You should have associations between tables A, B, C. Then id of type auto int would be sufficient.

Comment: I see, there is subof field - still I would prefer a simple int id without any encoded meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use GROUP BY to sum the qty, UNION ALL to combine different grouping in smae result and finnaly CTE for the base query

```
; with cte as
(
    select  ID1 = a.ID, Name1 = a.Name,
            ID2 = b.ID, Name2 = b.Name,
            ID3 = c.ID, Name3 = c.Name,
            t.Qty
    from    Trans t
            inner join tableC c on  t.ID    = c.ID
            inner join tableB b on  c.SubOf = b.ID
            inner join tableA a on  b.SubOf = a.ID
)
select  ID = ID1, Name = Name1, sum(Qty)
from    cte
group by ID1, Name1
union all
select  ID = ID2, Name = Name2, sum(Qty)
from    cte
group by ID2, Name2
union all
select  ID = ID3, Name = Name3, sum(Qty)
from    cte
group by ID3, Name3
```